# Inno setup / pascal scripting - is there any way to use Aero (dwmapi)?

Tags: delphi, inno-setup

I would like to build a custom setup, with an aero form, but I don't know how to start it.
Is there any way to use DWM API  with inno setup?

```
function dwm(Wnd: HWnd; cxLeftWidth, cxRightWidth, cyTopHeight, cyBottomHeight: integer ): Longint; external 'DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea@dwmapi.dll stdcall';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DWM API is a native API so you can access it using the [DLL Import method](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptdll).

Then you can call API functions in your script code.

But I would recommend against doing this.   Since the DWM only works on Vista or later and it can be disabled by stopping the NT Service.   It could prevent your installation from working on a machine that it was designed to work on.

Now that you posted your code...

Original declaration of the API you posted.

```
HRESULT WINAPI DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(
  HWND hWnd,
  __in  const MARGINS *pMarInset
);
```

My best guess is that it should look like this instead.

```
type
  Margins = record
    cxLeftWidth : Integer;
    cxRightWidth: Integer;
    cyTopHeight: Integer;
    cyBottomHeight: Integer;
  end;

function DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(Wnd: HWnd;
                                      var pMarInset : MARGINS) : 
                                 HRESULT; 
          external 'DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea@dwmapi.dll cdecl';
```

Comment: Yes, but I tried to call the function but inno setup crashes - updated code in the first post.

Comment: Crashes with what type of message?

Comment: With my code was Exception error, with this code the compiler says: Unknown type 'HRESULT'

Comment: You may need to upgrade to later version of InnoSetup as it recognized with 5.4.2. unicode.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, but now don't recognizes when I want to apply: DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(wizardform.handle, (0,0,50,0));

Comment: Are you trying to place a glass border on the window?    As you have to Enable Composition first and possible other things and that is just from my reading of the API

Comment: @user830054 : The `MarInset` parameter is declared as `var` so you couldn't pass a record literal. You have to define a local variable of type `MARGINS` first and pass that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the third party tool ISSkin for inno setup

http://isskin.codejock.com/

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would not use such an approach in a setup program, but if you you really need it I would develop it in Delphi, wrap it in a DLL with a simpler API, and call that DLL from InnoSetup.